# Why does jQuery show the wrong page?

Tags: jquery, html

This is the jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.ui-slider-switch', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'on') {
        $("#content1").hide();
        $("#content2").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#content1").show();
        $("#content2").hide();
    }
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="switch" data-role="fieldcontain">      
    <select name="slider" id="flip-a" data-role="slider">
        <option value="off"></option>
        <option value="on"></option>
    </select>   
</div>
```

In my site I sometimes use a custom URL (and get data out of it with `$ _GET`).
When the page reloads I'm always getting `$("#content2").show();` instead of `$("#content1").show();`

Comment: Do you mean, just after the reload? Or there are some times when you reload, and every time you change it it keeps showing only content2? Please clarify this point. Confirm also that the code is running (after a page reload, no change event has happened yet, or am I mistaken?)

Comment: Do you use $_GET['some_param'] to set the either of your `option` becomes `selected`?

Comment: @mgibsonbr It's just after the reload. When I refresch the page content1 is well shown

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$(document).on('change', '.ui-slider-switch', function () {
```

to:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=slider]', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the code in your event handler is running? (i.e. have you tested it using `alert` or `console.log` or something like that?) If the page just reloaded, and nobody (person or code) changed the select's value, the handler in principle won't run.

I'd suggest manually triggering the `change` event after your page (or the elements) finished loading, this way the correct value will be checked/double checked:

```
$('.ui-slider-switch').trigger('change');
```

Make sure that code is run after you page just finished reloading.